# Using an aspx page like an asmx service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asmx

Is it bad, from a scalability perspective, to use an ASPX page as though it were an ASMX service?

Specifically, we've set up an ASPX page whose code behind simply looks at what data was posted to it, does some operations, and Response.Writes the results.  jQuery treats the results like json, and all is good; it works.

My question is, will this solution suffer from a scalability perspective, compared to ASMX or WCF?  I know these technologies have all sorts of features to make the *code* more simple, but I'm merely asking about performance and scalability.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx

Comment: I will really like to hear what you think about what I came up with: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18749924/601179 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should need to Visit this links [WCF VS ASMX](http://keithelder.net/2008/10/17/wcf-vs-asmx-webservices/)
[WCF VS ASMX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa496123)

Comment: This really just talks about the greater power and configurability that WCF offers.  I'm asking whether using an ASPX page as an ad hoc web service will cause scalability problems down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a good answer but, if you want results like json, WCF supports rest services which are similar to calling aspx pages.
You can get detailed information from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx).

Comment: Again, I already know that WCF provides many features that asmx and aspx lack.  I'm asking about whether there are any scalability problems with using a single aspx page to act, essentially, as an ad hoc web service.